# FedEx REST API - Upload Document error (multipart stream ended)

Tags: rest, fedex

I am testing the FedEx REST API via Python. I am able to perform the authentication and e.g. validate a shipment - however, I am unable to perform an Upload Documents POST request. The [official FedEx docs](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/upload-documents/v1/docs.html) unfortunately seem to lack a correct example for this (as of 21.02.2023)

My code is below:

```
url = "https://documentapitest.prod.fedex.com/sandbox/documents/v1/etds/upload"

f = open("file.txt", "rb")
text_data = f.read()
f.close()


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "x-customer-transaction-id": "12XXXXXX",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
}

response = requests.post(
    url,
    files=dict(
        document='{"workflowName":"ETDPreshipment","name":"file.txt","contentType":"text/plain","meta":{"shipDocumentType":"COMMERCIAL_INVOICE","originCountryCode":"DK","destinationCountryCode":"BE"}',
        attachment=("file.txt", text_data, "text/plain")
    ),
    headers=headers,
)

print(response.text)
```

I get an error code `503` with the response.text providing the following error:

```
 {  
  "customerTransactionId": "12XXXXXX",
   "errors":[  
         {  
            "code":"SERVICE.NOT.AVAILABLE",
            "message":"Enterprise Document Upload Service Unavailable"
         }
      ]
}
```

I am unsure if this indicates an error in my script, or if the 'Upload Documents' API is only supported for production environments?

Comment: `503` typically indicates there's an issue server-side.

Comment: I have also tried running this with activated production credentials. In this case I get the following error instead: {  
 "customerTransactionId": "",
   "errors":[  
         {  
            "code":"AUTHENTICATION.TOKEN.INVALID",
            "message":"Invalid token passed in the request"
         }
      ]
}

Comment: I suggest trying postman for API debugging once you were able to hit api successfully then write code for it in your case it looks like FedEx doesn't have updated documentation for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, there are a few issues that could cause errors:

The Content-Type header should be set to "multipart/form-data; boundary=" where  is a unique string that separates the different parts of the request. In your code, you're only setting the "multipart/form-data" part of the header.

The JSON data for the document parameter should be passed as a separate parameter rather than as part of the attachment. You can do this using the data parameter in the files dictionary.

Here is the new code i changed here check.

```
url = "https://documentapitest.prod.fedex.com/sandbox/documents/v1/etds/upload"

f = open("file.txt", "rb")
text_data = f.read()
f.close()

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "x-customer-transaction-id": "12XXXXXX",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
}

data = {
    "document": '{"workflowName":"ETDPreshipment","name":"file.txt","contentType":"text/plain","meta":{"shipDocumentType":"COMMERCIAL_INVOICE","originCountryCode":"DK","destinationCountryCode":"BE"}}'
}

files = {
    "attachment": ("file.txt", text_data, "text/plain")
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

print(response.text)
```